# $n$ couples in $2n$ round table question: probability of the event where only $k$ couples are seated together

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A group of $2n$ individuals, which consists of $n$ married couples, are randomly seated around a round table with all possible seating arrangements being equally probable.

Let $P(k)$ denote the probability of the event where **only** $k$ couples are seated together. The problem is to determine how to calculate $P(k)$? Is there closed formula for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The answer has been amended to remove an anomaly arising from both unnmbered\numbered circle concepts inadvertently entering the formula*

**Note**
In the paper by Bogart and Doyle on the menage problem, they have made all computations as if the circle were numbered. However, I have used an unnumbered circle, which I found expedient

There isn't a closed formula, use the generalised principle of inclusion-exclusion, as *exactly* has been specified.

For $k$ couples together, let $S_k = \binom{n}{k}2^k(2n-1-k)!$

[ Couples to be together are chosen, glued together and flippable. The rest are free to be permuted in the remaining part remembering that the circle is unnumbered ]

Then exactly $k$ couples together
$$\binom{k}0S_k - \binom{k+1}1S_{k+1} \,+... - ....+ ...\binom{n}{n-k}S_n$$

To give it a semblance of being a closed formula, write

$$P(k)=\;\sum_{j=k}^{n}\; \frac{(-1)^{j-k}\;\binom{j}{j-k}\;S_{j}} {(2n-1)!}$$

Comment: How would the fact that the seats are numbered yield different results from unnumbered seats? The probability of exactly $k$ couples sitting together shouldn't be affected by whether someone scribbled down digits on the backs of the chairs.

Comment: @trueblueanil why is the denominator $(2n)!$ instead of $(2n-1!)$ ?

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish: See https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/menage/menage/menage.html

Comment: @trueblueanil well my old friend, i see now, $+1$

Comment: @Arthur: You are right in your comment. However, since *probability* has been asked for, both options are open. I was caught between two stools, but have streamlined to treat the circle as unnumbered.